# Facebook Android SDK Automatically Logging In

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the following facebook-sdk version:

```
com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
```

I use the default facebook login button for the login view

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="85dp" />`
```

With the following Java code

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList(permissions));
 LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
       //details intentionally hidden
 }
```

But for logging out, I use a custom button where on click I do the following

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
```

But the Facebook login button re logs in without being clicked! This just loops continuously!

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to register the callback with `LoginButton` so it only calls when button is clicked.

use below code: in `OnCreate()`

```
 loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
 List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList( "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends");
loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);

loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

         @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) { and so on }
```

Comment: I use `LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback`, so this doesn't works?

Comment: And what about Logout? `LoginManager.getInstance.logOut();` will work??

Comment: `LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback`...will work but i guess you are initiating it in your `onCreate()` so every time it gets call...you need to call it in your button click event...and logout will work.